# Which sets are by definiton countable/uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are there some general rules on whether a set is countable or not? Thus far I only know about $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ being uncountable, so I wonder if there are possibly any theorems that ascertain the countability/uncountability for sets, i.e., the cartesian product of a set, the power set of a set... etc. Is there maybe an intuitive way to see that? Other than going by the definition of countability itself.

Thank you very much!

Comment: On intuition: a set $A$ is countable if there is a way to count the elements one by one (first $a_1$, then $a_2$, et cetera) such that every element has its turn (provided that you keep on counting). For instance $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\dots$ for the set of integers. Another example: $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(3,0),\dots$ for the set $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Comment: By definition depends on the definition. But generally, every set that is countable is countable definition, and it is otherwise uncountable by definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a set $S$ contains an uncountable set, then $S$ is uncountable too. So, every set that contains, say, $\Bbb R$, is uncountable. Also, if $S$ is an infinite set, the set $\mathcal P(S)$ of all subsets of $S$ is uncountable. In particular, $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable.

On the other hand, any subset of a countable set is coubtable. And uny countable union of countable sets is also countable.

Comment: Note that in this answer, "contains" means "contains as a subset." There are sets which are countable, but which contain uncountable sets as elements.

Answer (score 3):

For the Cartesian product of two sets, you basically multiply the cardinalities.  In the case of infinite cardinality, you get the larger cardinality back.  I have jumped up to infinite *cardinality*, since the distinction between countable and  uncountable is really just the beginning of the story.

This is just a special case of Cantor's "infinite paradise", and its cardinal arithmetic.

For instance, in the case of power sets, the cardinality of the power set of a set is always greater than the cardinality of the original set:  $|\mathcal P(A)|\gt|A|$, by Cantor's famous *diagonal argument*.  Particularly salient is the proof that the real numbers are not countable, since if you claim you could put them in a list, it is possible by the diagonal argument to construct a real not in the list by changing the diagonal entry on each element.

Answer (score 2):

A set non-empty set $X$ is countable iff there is a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ iff there is an injection $i:X\to\mathbb{N}$ iff there is a surjection $s:\mathbb{N}\to X$.

Just as another piece of information, if $A$ is a set and $B$ is a proper subset of $A$ and there is a bijection $f:A\to B$, then $A$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a set $\mathcal{S}$ can be called countable, if there exists a bijective function $f$ between $\mathcal{S}$ and the set of natural numbers: $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{S} \overset{f}{\sim} \mathbb{N}$). In this case we can say that sets $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are [equinumerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity), and that is any set, which is equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}$ is called countable.

Comment: For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, since there exists a bijective map of $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, such that: $f(n) = (-1)^{n}(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{4}) - \frac{1}{4}.$ That is we have a map by $f$: $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, n \rightarrow f(n) : 0 \rightarrow 0, 1 \rightarrow -1, 2 \rightarrow 1, 3 \rightarrow 2, 4 \rightarrow -2, $ etc. Same logic applied to $f^{-1}$ provides you a bijection.